# Sort JSON data based on a specific word in a property of an object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sorting

I want sort data from a json file.

I have following `data.json` json File content:
Each package is a object with two properties.

```
{
    "attr_2.4.48": {
      "exposed": false,
      "score": "Not qualified"
    },
    "cockpit_218": {
      "exposed": false,
      "score": "partial qualified"
    },
    "base-passwd_3.5.29": {
        "exposed": false,
        "score": "Qualified"
    },
    "audit_2.8.5": {
      "exposed": true,
      "score": "partial qualified"
    },
    "base-files_3.0.14": {
      "exposed": false,
      "score": "Not qualified"
    }
}
```

The output should be sorted in following way:

- first all packages with `"score": "Not qualified"`
- second all packages with `"score": "partial qualified"`
- and last all packages with `"score": "Qualified"`

Each package with the same `score` should also be sorted alphabetically

The sorted data should look like this:

```
{
    "attr_2.4.48": {
        "exposed": false,
        "score": "Not qualified"
    },
    "base-files_3.0.14": {
        "exposed": false,
        "score": "Not qualified"
    },
    "audit_2.8.5": {
        "exposed": true,
        "score": "partial qualified"
    },
    "cockpit_218": {
        "exposed": false,
        "score": "partial qualified"
    },
    "base-passwd_3.5.29": {
        "exposed": false,
        "score": "Qualified"
    }
}
```

My problem at the moment is, that i don't know how to sort the data based on the `socre` value.

My code is only sorting the packages by `score` value in alphabetical order:

```
with open(data.json, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
     json_content = json.load(json_file)

package = content.keys()
sorted_content = sorted(package, key=lambda ip: content[ip]['score'], reverse=False)
```

How can I update my code so that the data looks like the output shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `json_content` is your parsed json file you can do:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

order = ["Not qualified", "partial qualified", "Qualified"]

json_content = OrderedDict(
    sorted(
        json_content.items(), key=lambda i: (order.index(i[1]["score"]), i[0])
    )
)

print(json.dumps(json_content, indent=4, sort_keys=False))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "attr_2.4.48": {
        "exposed": false,
        "score": "Not qualified"
    },
    "base-files_3.0.14": {
        "exposed": false,
        "score": "Not qualified"
    },
    "audit_2.8.5": {
        "exposed": true,
        "score": "partial qualified"
    },
    "cockpit_218": {
        "exposed": false,
        "score": "partial qualified"
    },
    "base-passwd_3.5.29": {
        "exposed": false,
        "score": "Qualified"
    }
}
```